# I'm receiving an error accessing api calls when deployed to a subfolder

Tags: abp

I have developed a web app using ABP.IO version 5.0 (also same issue using 4.4.3).NET Core Razor pages. In the development environment everything works fine. If I deploy the application to IIS as a root-level site (access URL like https://{my site}), everything works fine. I deploy it as an application under a root-level site (access URL like https://{parent site}/{my site}) I can access the login page and hit the Identity Server, but all subsequent calls that hit the API fail. The URL for calls to the API drop the {my site} portion of the URL and I get a 404 error. The calls to the API look like https://{parent site}/api/{controller}/{method} instead of https://{parent site}/{my site}/api/{controller}/{method}.

I found a setting for the appsettings.json file (AppSelfURL) that I thought might help resolve the issue but it did nothing.

Is there a setting that forces the app to retain the complete base URL when making the calls to the API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Modified the definition of the problem and request for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

ABP supports sub-application deployment.
You can check this: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/4101